# How to automatically remove certain preprocessors directives and comments from a C header-file?

Tags: python, string

What's a good way to remove all text from a file which lies between `/* */` and `#if 0` and corresponding `#endif`? I want to strip these parts from C headers. This is the code I have so far:

```
For line in file:

    if def0Encountered == 0:  
        if Line.strip().startswith('#if 0') == True:  
            Def0StartsAt = Line.find('#if 0')  
            def0Encountered = 1  
            if Line.find('#endif')!= -1:  
                def0Encountered = 0  
                Def0EndsAt = Line.find('endif')  
                Line = Line[0:Def0StartsAt] + Line[Def0EndsAt + 2 : ]  
                List = Line.split()
```

Comment: Please reformat your question with Markdowns. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Can CPP really cope with `#if 0 ... #endif` all on a single line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to replace the parts of the file you don't want with the empty string (Note, this is very basic, it won't work e.g. for nested macros):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

# uncomment/comment for test with a real file ...
# header = open('mycfile.c', 'r').read()
header = """

#if 0
    whatever(necessary)
    and maybe more

#endif

/* 
 * This is an original style comment
 *
 */

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */
    return 0;
}

"""

p_macro = re.compile("#if.*?#endif", re.DOTALL)
p_comment = re.compile("/\*.*?\*/", re.DOTALL)

# Example ...
# print re.sub(p_macro, '', header)
# print re.sub(p_comment, '', header)
```

Comment: @miku: I am not good with regex syntax, but does this cover the case of nested `#if`s?

Comment: thanks so if along with this I use header= file.readlines it will work on the whole C file ?

Comment: @Space: No, no nested `#if`. You'd need more than a regular grammar/expression for that. But good point, I'll add a note to my post.

Comment: @praveen: Updated my post to include the file handling. As @Space pointed out, nested `#if`s won't be matched correctly with this version.

Comment: Also to make it complete , dump the output in new file

Comment: @miku @Space_C0wb0y Could you give me an exemple of nested  #if , please

Comment: @miku re.MULTILINE is useless, as characters ^ and $ are not present in the RE "#if.*?#endif" and the other one too

Comment: @eyquem: Thanks, removed `MULTILINE`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what this strange code should be doing but it is straight forward to iterate over the file line-by-line. Use two flags to check if you are inside a comment or and if block. Toggle the the flags based on string comparisions. Based on the value of both flags you either output the current line or ignore it....