# string, regular expressions in python

Tags: python, string

From the following question
[How to automatically remove certain preprocessors directives and comments from a C header-file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388620/how-to-automatically-remove-certain-preprocessors-directives-and-comments-from-a)

```
header = "" #some string

p_macro = re.compile("#if.*?#endif", re.MULTILINE + re.DOTALL)  
p_comment = re.compile("/\*.*?\*/", re.MULTILINE + re.DOTALL)   


# Example ...
# print re.sub(p_macro, '', header)
# print re.sub(p_comment, '', header)
```

This however results in a failure for a case like

```
#endif // #if 0
```

What could be added in the re expression to avoid this?

Comment: This is why regular expressions do not make parsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
p_macro = re.compile("#(end)?if.*?#(?(1)|end)if",re.DOTALL)
```

re.MULTILINE is useless because there is no character '^' and no '$' in the RE

Possibly, you will have to add such correction endlessly.....